# How can I know the privileges against a file in Linux?

Tags: linux

> **Cross-posted:** [How can I know the privileges against a file in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/knowing-privilege-rights-on-a-file-in-linux)

I have logged into a Linux server as a normal user (not as an admin) to see some shell scripts in a directory. Assume that a file named `Denem.sh` is present in the directory.

How can I know which rights / privileges are provided to me for that file `(Denem.sh)`? How would I see if it is read-only or if I can modify it?

Comment: have you test the command "ls -l". The man-page for ls: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command

```
ls -l Denem.sh
```

to show the permissions on a file. The command displays:

```
-rwxrwxrwx    doggie   users   29212      May 12 09:59    Denem.sh
permissions   owner    group   filesize   last modified   filename
```

If you want to modify the permissions, you can use

```
chmod +x Denem.sh
```

to give execute permissions.

Comment: Why do you say to run `ls` with `-a`? It does nothing in this case.

Comment: @camh : you are correct. Sorry, force of habit.